# Strip a long php string

Tags: php, string

I want to strip a long php string containing a lot of text to output only the complete first 3 sentences only.

I looked around SO posts and found some answers regarding delimiters. But, doing

```
$pieces = preg_split('/[.]/', $mystring)
```

would store all the sentences in the `$pieces` variable, and take unnecessary space as I would only like to output the first 3 pieces only. Is there any better way?

Input: A string containing sentences of more than 5000 characters.

Output: The first 3 sentences.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want here; you want to take a block of text and split it into individual sentences, or something else? Can you give example input / desired output to further clarify?

Comment: You have to provide example: source data and desired result

Comment: Can you tell us: 1)  the largest amount of memory used by the input string? 2) the cost of parsing that string into a temporary array, getting the first 3 element then freeing or re-using that temporary array. In terms of memory? Some actual number values would be useful.

Comment: @xan There is neither _example input_ nor _desired output_

Comment: @hindmost: I added an input/output case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid storing every part, you may use `strtok`, to [tokenize the string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) by period as follows:

```
<?php
$string = "This is an example. string. string. etc. etc.";
$tok = strtok($string, ".");

$i = 0;
while (($tok !== false) && ($i < 3)) {
    echo "Sentence=$tok<br />";
    $tok = strtok(".");
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Sentence=This is an example
Sentence= string
Sentence= string
```